# Combine two columns in R where one of them is a list

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
data <- tibble(
  video = c("Daniel", "Laura"),
  color = list("")
)

data$color[1] <- list(c("blue", "red", "black"))
data$color[2] <- list(c("yellow", "orange"))
```

I want to transform `data` to get this result:

```
Daniel - blue
Daniel - red
Daniel - black
Laura - yellow
Laura - orange
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Please describe what you've tried by providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    unnest(c(color))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  video  color 
#  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 Daniel blue  
#2 Daniel red   
#3 Daniel black 
#4 Laura  yellow
#5 Laura  orange
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  group_by(video) %>% 
  mutate(color = str_c(color %>% unlist(.), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  separate_rows(color, sep = ",")

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   video [2]
  video  color 
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Daniel blue  
2 Daniel red   
3 Daniel black 
4 Laura  yellow
5 Laura  orange
```

Comment: Or `tidyr::unnest(data)`

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most efficient way to do it (especially if your data set is really large) but it does what you need ;-)

```
data <- tibble(
  video = c("Daniel", "Laura"),
  color = list("")
)

data$color[1] <- list(c("blue", "red", "black"))
data$color[2] <- list(c("yellow", "orange"))

# Initiate empty df
df <- data.frame(video=character(),
                 color=character())
for (i in data$video) {
  count <- length(unlist(data$color[which(data$video==i)]))
  video_ <- rep(data$video[which(data$video==i)],count)
  color_ <- unlist(data$color[which(data$video==i)])
  df_ <- cbind(video_, color_)
  df <- rbind(df, df_)
}
colnames(df) <- c("video", "color")
```

Comment: Or `tidyr::unnest(data)` ;)